# Running a function after loading an external script

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way, with JavaScript ES6, to load a script and then run a function after that script is ready? Basically loading the script through JavaScript,  waiting until it's ready to use, then running a function that might methods etc. from the loaded script.

For instance, a simple way to do this with jQuery is:

```
$.getScript('foo.js', function() {
   runFunction();
});
```

Is there a reliable alternative to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.** You should use a *Promise*. Specific to network related requests, see the Fetch api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks - I looked into promises and this seems to work well. One question, will this check if the script is already loaded, or will it load the script twice? Is there anyway to check if loaded first?

Comment: When developing in a browser, it will generally cache requests. This depends on a lot of factors. I suggest you research how the browser works with regard to asset caching.